# Datatypes with haskelldb in practice (Text, UTCTime)

Tags: haskell, haskelldb

I just started to look into `haskelldb` as a more powerful companion to `persistent`, as I need a more powerful tool to query the database. Almost immediately I ran into difficulties with datatypes; in particular, I am using `Data.Text` quite extensively, `UTCTime` too and some custom datatypes as well. Unfortunately, although HDBC seems to support these datatypes quite well, haskelldb hides all of this and you have to write your own conversions starting from `String` input.

I don't want to duplicate the work already done for HDBC; what do you suggest to do in this case?

I think I will probably add an attribute `getHdbcValue` into the `GetInstances` class, so that I can write simple `GetValue` instances that would leverage the HDBC infrastructure; are there any better ideas? Am I missing something obvious?

(BTW: it seems to me that this library is - maybe from historical reasons - a little over-generalized; couldn't it just support hdbc..? )

Comment: Is persistent really that limited? I think the Yesod people use it for everything, so I'd be surprised if there's much HaskellDB can do that it can't. Of course, HaskellDB might be able to do some things in a more simple manner than persistent.

Comment: Yes. Persistent is supposed to be really database-agnostic, while haskelldb is centered around SQL. Persistent doesn't support DB functions, custom operators, even slightly more complex joins. I wouldn't blame persistent, most ORM frameworks don't support such features, but in most my applications accessing DB I need them.

Comment: have you evaluated esqueleto?

Answer (score 2):

I really love PostgreSQL and its rich type collection, particularly arrays. Most used of the extra PG types across projects outside Haskell is [int4], typical array of ints. Bringing the support for it to HaskellDB became one of the most exciting challenges I've had on my road to understanding Haskell, especially type-level programming (and TH/QQ too). Adding a new type to support looks kinda easy as long as it is supported by HDBC.

Hope this little patch could show how to add support for a new type. Here's the pull request for that, almost all changes needed covered here(all that is left is FlexibleInstances):

[Pull Request](https://github.com/m4dc4p/haskelldb/pull/8)

[Main Changeset](https://github.com/deep-orca/haskelldb-intarray/commit/4ea209b50f07ca44b55fc8aae0d6ce7b0c275821)

Comment: The "Pull Request" link returns a 404.